# Get a subfolder using SharePoint CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am wanting to get a folder within Shared Documents on a SharePoint site using CSOM in order to add files to it.
Here is my current code:

```
        // Get the folder we want to add images to
        var context = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl)
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
        Web web = context.Web;
        Folder targetFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared%20Documents/" + nameOfTargerFolder);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

And I am getting this error: "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web object has a serverrelativeurl property:
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.serverrelativeurl?view=sharepoint-server

Try this:

```
    // Get the folder we want to add images to
    var context = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl)
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Folder targetFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/" + nameOfTargerFolder);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: You need to first load the `web.ServerRealtiveUrl` otherwise the error will persist.

Comment: Also needed to insert another `context.ExecuteQuery()` after loading web.ServerRelativeUrl. This solution worked great for me!